# Можно ли использовать ресурсные контроллеры для работы в публичной части сайта?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Я создаю страницу оформления заказа в публичной части сайта, и не понял, могу ли я использовать ресурсные контроллеры, чтобы пользователь мог создать заказ, удалять его и всё остальное. По сути, это же дефолтный круд, да?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вопрос сразу же возникает: а зачем? Можно всё, но это не значит, что это будет правильно. Вы же нарушаете так безопасность...

Comment: а в чём проблема? ресурсный контроллер никак не влияет на безопасность, он лишь помогает не писать руками все эти методы и маршруты. Безопасность того или иного метода определяете сами. По сути в контроллере если пользователь не админ на пример нажимает создать заказ, он создаёт его из своей корзины. Удалить заказ соответственно он может свой, как и  посмотреть и получить список всех своих. То есть все те же методы, только ограничение идет по роли пользователя. Админ может делать это с любым заказом а пользователь только со своими. Вот и вся магия.

Answer (score 0):

да, можно, вы же сами описываете логику в каждом методе.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.